# Embedded Youtube not working after implementing SSL certificate due to mixed content issue

Tags: javascript, html, ssl-certificate, lightbox, mixed-content

We have installed an SSL certificate and now our website is served over HTTPS.

The website seems to be working fine, the only problem is with YouTube videos that I am playing as Popups using `nivo-lightbox`.  I am getting the error below:

`Blocked loading mixed active content "http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx"`

After this, I changed the YouTube URL to `https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx` but it still doesn't work.

After checking the same video in the FireFox debugger, it still shows the URL as `http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx`.  When I click the play button to play video, the actual URL uses HTTPS:

```
<p><a class="btn play" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxx">Play Video</a></p>
```

I'm not sure if the `nivo-lightbox` script is changing the `https` to `http`, what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue after going through the `Nivo Lightbox v1.2.0` below part of code had `http://` which i changed to `https://` and then all was fine

```
// Video (Youtube/Vimeo)
            else if(video){
                var src = '',
                    classTerm = 'nivo-lightbox-video';

                if(video[1] == 'youtube'){
                    src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ video[4];
                    classTerm = 'nivo-lightbox-youtube';
                }
                if(video[1] == 'youtu'){
                    src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ video[3];
                    classTerm = 'nivo-lightbox-youtube';
                }
                if(video[1] == 'vimeo'){
                    src = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ video[3];
                    classTerm = 'nivo-lightbox-vimeo';
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not youtube videos ,since I also changed the youtube videos on the page from http to https and it is not giving mixed content error.The problem seems to be with the ivo-lightbox.You can verify this after directly embedding the youtube videos in a div without any plugin or library.If you are not get any warning after this then you need to enable https in lightbox.